# Force delete a directory

Tags: linux, file-permissions, sd-card

I have a FAT32 SD card with a file on it, that, viewed in Windows the filename consists of a long string of nonsense.

[image]

Viewed in my Android phone's Linux terminal, `ls -a` shows nothing in the directory.  When I try to delete the parent directory with `rm -rf deleteme`, it fails with "Directory not empty".  When I try to delete/move in Windows 7, it says the filename would be too long and/or Explorer crashes.  Windows disk check doesn't find anything wrong.

How can I delete this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `cmd.exe` command

`dir /-N`

shows the alternative DOS 8.3 character file names that are always present on FAT32. Use this name for the `del` command.

Comment: `______~1                  1,303 2010-07-07  11:56 PM`  It worked!

Answer (score 0):

Also run top -u {your user name} and make sure that nothing's running that's using that directory when you're trying to delete it.

Hope that helps.